# "Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!"

Tags: discussion, flagging

I think I have a reasonable flag record. Unless this is a bug, then something new has happened. But what?

Comment: Check [this page to review your flags](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/121097).

Comment: It seems that [at least 25% of your flags from the past seven days were declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405). That counts post flags only, not comment flags.

Comment: That new feature could use some fine-tuning -- I have 320 helpful flags (and 24 declined), but since I don't flag much these days (work...) and one flag was declined, I got the warning...

Comment: @DanielFischer I have to admit that this is a great feature. (Btw, when improve that poor searching engine? It stays so for years.)

Comment: In any case it's better than the old flag-hellban. You've recently been a little unlucky and flagged several answers that were already through the review queue.

Comment: @DanielFischer And how long will last this ban? Days, months, years?

Comment: These temporary bans always last at most one week. It looks like you haven't flagged posts in the last three days, so it should be at most four days left.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I can't figure out what a hellban is from following that link. Can you clarify?

Comment: It's when one is banned, but isn't notified of it. One can do things, but those aren't shown to other users of the site. The old flag hell-ban was that once the flag-weight dropped too low, the flags were silently ignored by the system. No chance of recovery, no notification.